# H2: "data conversion error" in WHERE clause

Tags: java, database, oracle, exception, h2

I am using the H2 database (v1.3.170) for JUnit testing in my project. Our production environment uses Oracle DB so we have to do lot conversions of the DDLs exported from Oracle to make them working with H2. One of the issues we are facing right now is following:

```
select * from table_country c where c.code > 0 AND 'USA' = c.name(+)
```

This query works fine in Oracle, but fails in H2 with below stack trace:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "USA"; SQL statement:
select * from table_country c where c.code>0 AND 'USA' = c.name(+) [22018-170] 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158) 
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:852) 
    at org.h2.value.Value.getBoolean(Value.java:373) 
    at org.h2.expression.ConditionAndOr.optimize(ConditionAndOr.java:188) 
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:802) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218) 
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:414) 
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:253) 
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:149) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException 
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source) 
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source) 
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:801) 
    ... 8 more
```

I tried removing the (+) - it worked:

```
select * from table_country c where c.code > 0 AND 'USA' = c.name
```

But as I said, I don't want to change this in production (want the Oracle => H2 conversion to be transparent).

Please suggest what could be the issue and a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`(+)` syntax for outer joins is deprecated in Oracle. Stop using it.

In your case an "outer join" doesn't really makes sense anyway because you are not joining.

You probably want something like this (which works reliably across all DBMS)

```
select * 
from table_country c 
where c.code > 0 
  and (c.name = 'USA' or c.name is null);
```

A final word: using a different DBMS for testing and production makes your tests worthless. There are too many subtle differences between the DBMS that you simply can't cover when using different DBMS.

Comment: I agree, except that I believe using a different DBMS for testing has a few advantages, for example you can more easily run unit tests (because you may not have Oracle on your developer machine). Plus in many cases the unit tests are faster, specially when using an in memory database. It's kind of the same reason to use mock objects for testing: yes they may not behave in the exact same way as the real environment. But a test environment is by definition a simplification of the real world. Actually most programming is about simplifying the real world.

Comment: @ThomasMueller: I understand the reasoning, but in my experience this simply doesn't work. Think about simple (ANSI SQL) statement like: `select * from foo where order_date < current_timestamp - interval '1' month;`. Or run this SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1e24/2 in H2 and you'll wind up with duplicate rows that you don't expect.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name said "(+) syntax for outer joins is deprecated in Oracle". you sure about that ?

Comment: @Haki: yes I am. From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#i2054062 : "*Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator*"

Comment: This is news to me. thanks for the update. i've experienced some bugs on 10G with the new ANSI syntax (mostly with MV's) and ever since i'm using only the old syntax. good to know.

Comment: @haki The old-style Oracle outer join syntax using `(+)` is actually partially supported by H2, but this support isn't complete (as you see in your example) and the remaining support be removed in the future for H2 because of that. I suggest to not use it (for both Oracle and H2).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the example, this is a known incompatibility between Oracle and other databases (PostgreSQL and so on). H2 supports the Oracle behavior for this case, but you need to use the [Oracle compatibility mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility). This is the feature "When using unique indexes, multiple rows with NULL in all columns are allowed, however it is not allowed to have multiple rows with the same values otherwise."

Comment: @ThomasMueller: The index handling is just *one* example (and the `interval` literall still won't work in Oracle mode). There are others that I know off (simply replace the NULL in the second insert with an empty string `''`...), and I'm sure there are (a lot) others that I don't know off.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right, there are unfortunately quite many incompatibilities that a typical user is not aware of. And I'm not saying test should not be run against the production database - they should, in the nightly build at least. I'm just saying that running tests against _another_ database (at development time) is a good idea, for multiple reasons: speed (development "velocity"), to be able to run the tests locally where Oracle isn't available, and to find out about differences between databases, such that switching the application to use a different database is simpler.